# 'gap://ready' is not getting served over https

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova

I have tried adding various  tags and tried adding relative path: '//'

These are various meta tags that I have tried

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' "> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content=" style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; frame-src  * ;"> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * data: blob: gap: 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' ws: wss:;"> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' ; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' blob: gap: data: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; object-src *; style-src 'self' data: 'unsafe-inline'; img-src 'self' data:; media-src 'self' data:; font-src 'self' data:;frame-src gap: about: ; connect-src *"/>
```

And I have tried adding '//' for relative path too.

```
    execIframe.contentWindow.location = '//gap://ready';
    execIframe.src = '//gap://ready';
    document.body.appendChild(execIframe);
```

Still, I am not able to serve the gap://ready over https which is required.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try adding this one

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * gap://ready data:; img-src * 'self' data:; style-src * 'unsafe-inline'; script-src * 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; ">
```

Comment: This is a wide-open CSP and is quite insecure. I'm not sure what the point of having a CSP in place is if wildcards are going to be used so liberally like this.